# Rustlang Macro $operator= seen as syntax error

Tags: rust, macros, rust-macros

So I wrote this macro in Rustlang to allow me to create multiple functions fast that accepts a bunch of values and then perform an arithmetic operation (or may be other operations, hence the need for it to remain dynamic enough) on them this way `special_fn!(add, 4, i32, +);`

Here is the code.

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! special_fn {
    ($func:ident, $n:expr, $t:ty, $op:tt) => {

        pub fn $func(values : Vec<$t>) -> $t{
            let mut result:$t;
             for x in 1..$n {
                result $op= values[x];
            }
            result
        }

    };
}
```

But this line is causing issues `result $op= values[x];` and it says `Expleced expression, found =`
[image]

However,

- I could use match expression or if expression to match all possible operations, but that will require more code
- I also found another way is this

```
macro_rules! special_fn {
    ($func:ident, $n:expr, $t:ty, $op:tt, $default:expr) => {

        pub fn $func(values : Vec<$t>) -> $t{
            let mut result:$t = $default;
             for x in 1..$n {
                result = result $op values[x];
            }
            result
        }

    };
}
```

But this will introduce another metavariable to the macro.
Is there another way that will keep the simplicity?

Comment: Note that you need default value anyway, since `result += value` and friends isn't valid when `result` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate `=` to an operator captured in `tt` (without a proc macro). `+=` is a single token, and if you do `$op=` it's like if you type `+ =`, which is invalid (I think a proc macro could do that, but I haven't tested).

You could pass `+=` to the macro instead of `+`, but as @Cerberus said, you need a default value anyway so just pass it (or use `Default::default()`).